# Перестают писаться логи. Log4Net

Tags: c#, логирование, log4net

Аппендер настроен, логи пишутся нормально до неизвестного момента времени, после которого логи перестают писаться вообще, хотя приложение работает стабильно. С чем может быть проблема?

```
<appender name="LocalFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="Logs\Log.log" />
  <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
  <maximumFileSize value="50MB" />
  <encoding value="utf-8" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d  %-5level:  %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Объем логов не превышает 5 мб

Comment: Попробуйте добавить параметр `<param name="ImmediateFlush" value="true" />`